# Create equal space between cells and between margins and cells UICollectionView

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have a UICollectionView. On certain devices, the cells hug the edges of the device, while having a big gap in the center. I have tried changing insets and minimum spacing, both of which did not work. I created this in the storyboard so I have no code related to formatting. How would I make the space between the cells equal to the space between the outer cells and the margins so there is not a huge gap in the middle? Thanks.

[image]

Edges of image are the exact edge of the device

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you're using `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` and your cell has fixed size:

#### Custom cell code: (I added some shadow and rounded corners, ignore it)

```
import UIKit

class CollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)


        layer.shadowColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
        layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 2.0)
        layer.shadowRadius = 5.0
        layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0
        layer.masksToBounds = false
        layer.shadowPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: bounds, cornerRadius: contentView.layer.cornerRadius).cgPath
        layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor

        contentView.layer.masksToBounds = true
        layer.cornerRadius = 10
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

### View controller code:

```
import UIKit

private let reuseIdentifier = "Cell"

class CollectionViewController: UICollectionViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        /// Class registration
        collectionView.register(CollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        /// Expected cell size
        let cellSize = CGSize(width: 120, height: 110)

        /// Number of columns you need
        let numColumns: CGFloat = 2
        /// Interitem space calculation
        let interitemSpace = ( UIScreen.main.bounds.width - numColumns * cellSize.width ) / (numColumns + 1)

        /// Setting content insets for side margins
        collectionView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 10, left: interitemSpace, bottom: 10, right: interitemSpace)

        /// Telling the layout which cell size it has
        (self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout as! UICollectionViewFlowLayout).itemSize = cellSize
    }

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 10
    }

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath)
        cell.backgroundColor = .white
        return cell
    }
}
```

#### Here is the result:

[image]